# unble to convert time to local time zone i.e IST

Tags: c#, datetime

im getting time like this

```
  2017-03-06T12:51:33.481Z

desired output time 



 3/6/2017, 6:21:33 PM
```

im getting time like this

3/6/2017 5:56:33 AM

data type is string

```
public string UpdatedTime { get; set; }
```

code

```
     string updtime = bin.timestamp;//03/06/2017 12:51:33
     string ISTTime = Convert.ToDateTime(updtime).ToString("M/d/yyyy, h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);//3/6/2017, 6:21:33 PM
                binModel.UpdatedTime = ISTTime;
```

Comment: `DateTime utcdate = bin.timestamp.ToString();` - that's not going to compile. Please provide a genuine [mcve].

Comment: updtime should be converted to local time zone(indian standard time), updated question

Comment: The updated question still doesn't contain a [mcve], and you're still trying to assign a `string` value to a `DateTime` variable. Hint: if I can't copy, paste, compile, then run, then it's not a complete example.

Comment: i have updated my question, im getting the date time in updtime variable, which i need to convert into IST time zone - and that should come - "3/6/2017, 6:21:33 PM"

Comment: That's *still* not a [mcve]. It's really not hard to create one - please put the effort in. Bear in mind that the primary goal of Stack Overflow is *not* to help you with your problem - it's to create a repository of high quality questions and answers. Currently this is *not* a high quality question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working for me:

```
        string updtime = "03/06/2017 12:51:33";
        string ISTTime = Convert.ToDateTime(updtime).ToString("M/d/yyyy, h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);//3/6/2017, 6:21:33 PM
        var ISTDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(Convert.ToDateTime(ISTTime), TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time"));
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help...sameer

Comment: This is doing more conversions than is healthy. Parse once (if at all), convert time zone once, format once (if at all). Those conversions are also assuming a particular date/time format will be the default - this code will do the wrong thing in some environments.